# Does there exist a sequence of continuous functions, and a dominating continuous funciton a.s.?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, approximation

Let $f\in L^1([a,b])$. Does there exist a sequence of continuous functions converging to $f$ in $L^1$ with a function $g\in L^1([a,b])$, where $g$ dominates the sequence a.s., and the set of points where $g$ is discontinuous has measure zero?

Note I asked a similar question here and got an answer: [Does there exist a bounding integrable continuous function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756127/does-there-exist-a-bounding-integrable-continuous-function)

Here the answer shows that for a given sequence, such a $g$ may not exist. However, what I am wondering is if there may exist a sequence and a $g$?(That is for a given sequence such a $g$ may not exist, but there could be another sequence where it does exist?)

EDIT:

I think the proof by @Nate Eldredge here shows that a dominating function may exist:
[Approximation of a $L^1$ function by a dominated sequence of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020956/approximation-of-a-l1-function-by-a-dominated-sequence-of-continuous-function)

Now I just need to know if that function can be such that the point of discontinuities have measure zero?